# HowTo get unique ID for any DukTape "thing" including array or object?

Tags: duktape

I am working on a (limited) C++ pickling/serialiser for (some) JavaScript/DukTape objects.
I want to keep track of which objects have been written.
For "normal" objects I (think that I) can mark them with a hidden \xFF field/property (maybe) and use that.

I am (now) trying to store arrays.
I need/want a way (from C/C++) to either "mark" arrays with a GUID or to find some sort of "instance ID" value unique to them.

Is this something that DukTape supports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays also have a property table so you should be able to use the same marking approach as you use for objects.

Comment: So, something like `duk_put_prop_string(ctx, array, "\xFF" "\xFF" "secret-encoded-id");` would let me mark the arrays and the objects?

Comment: That should work, "array" argument would be the value stack index pointing to the array (or object).